# Phones or other machines not connecting

Tags: linux, proxy, http-proxy, mitmproxy

I followed all the steps and installed mitmproxy in my virtual machine and then proceeded to test it.

I opened firefox and used the IP address I got from ifconfig. {inet address}

And it worked!

But when I to do the same for my other laptop or phone{with the ca certificate installed} connected to the same router. It does not connect. The proxy doesn't work.

[image]

As you can see it works in my PC where I have the vmware running linux and mitmproxy, but this proxy isn't working for my other machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed the 'Network' settings on my vmware to 'bridged'. And everything started working as expected.
Cheers,